# HTML "onsubmit" cancelling out the "action"

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

When running my onsubmit for the JavaScript validation, it cancels the action where my form details are added to a database. Once the onsubmit is taken away, the action function works, but with both of them there the action doesn't get called or work. Any fix to this?

```
<form onsubmit="return validation()" action="includes\submitContact.inc.php" method="post" id="form" >
```

Comment: post `validation()` please

Comment: If the validation method does not return true, the form submit will not happen.

Comment: Just solved it! Had a return false. Thanks @Berto99 for pointing me there! Its all working as it should now.

Comment: @DevB Given that you found the solution after debugging it from the comments, you should self post an answer showing what the issue was and how you fixed it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The return value of an event handler determines whether or not the action should be processed

I think validation returns `false` or `undefined` so nothing happens

Try

```js
<form onsubmit="validation()" action="includes\submitContact.inc.php" method="post" id="form" >
```

Edit:

This means the issue comes from there if above works, then you can debug safely why validation returns a falsy boolean

Comment: Without the return, the validation cannot cancel the submit on failure.

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for the input, I thought this was implicitly clear. I edited the answer to extend on this

Comment: Thanks! Helped, did indeed have a return false at the end of the validation.

Comment: "Do this and if it works, then you can debug" isn't a complete answer.  It does not solve the issue.

Comment: @Taplar Yes I agree, and your input made the answer more exhaustive. The issue on itself wasn't the clearest at first neither, maybe this is where we could have digged more before answering. Glad at least we guided our new community member towards a resolution!

Answer (score -1):

```
if(check == 1)
{
    errorMsg.style.backgroundColor="#28B463";
    errorMsg.style.color="white";
    text = "Form Successfully Submited"
    errorMsg.innerHTML = text;
    return false;
}
```

I was playing around with the JavaScript to change CSS styles, and due to the above code, a false return was happening, resulting in the "action" not running as it should.

Answer (score -2):

Probably validation function doesn't return **true**, it should return true to continue the submission

Comment: Thanks! Helped, did indeed have a return false at the end of the validation.